# htaccess access to folders via subdomains

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make a rule in .htaccess to access a folder via subdomain alias (with parameters).

```
sub.example.com => example.com/sub/index.php
sub.example.com/language-fr => example.com/sub/inner_page.php?lang=fr
```

I found a simple solution for subdomains with parameters.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/inner_page.php?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

This works correctly. When i browse to sub.example.com/language-fr  i am getting the contents of example.com/sub/inner_page.php?lang=fr
But this doesn't work when i browse sub.example.com i see error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Please tell me how to correctly specify the rules for accessing sub.example.com and internal pages with parameters like sub.example.com/language-fr ?

Comment: Have you got other rewriting rules rules concerning `example.com/sub/` that could help us explaining that (in this htaccess file or in `sub` directory)? Also, as I see your rule to redirect to `inner_page` the regex condition should also apply to `sub.example.com` because `(.*)` also matche empty. Maybe you can try with `^(.+)$`

Comment: I have no other rewriting rules. Also tried ^(. +)$ , but same result. I can't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Ok then 2 other tests: do `example.com/sub/` instead of using the subdomain leads where you want to? And second: when you remove the rule to redirect to `inner_page.php`, does it work acessing to `sub.example.com`?

Comment: When I do example.com/sub/ it works correctly.
When I delete the rules, I see content from the main domain example.com.

Comment: Maybe I need to add some rules to the .htaccess of the sub folder?

Comment: Next test was too long for a comment, I added as an answer, if it doesn't work I'll try to fix it or delete it..

Answer (score 0):

I actually cannot explain in detail why you enter a redirection loop here.. but this should be a working solution.

`RewriteCond` one after another add each other using AND (unless you use the `[OR]` flag)

I would use this on the `%{REQUEST_URI}` to prevent each case to be detected by the other (`^$` means "empty"):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /sub/inner_page.php?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$
RewriteRule ^$ /sub/index.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Very strange, but when i visit sub.example.com, it still gets infinite redirects. I cannot understand what leads to the error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Comment: OK I'll do some tests on a local server and come back